При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
когда что то пытаюсь установить через терминал всегда вылезает такая ошибка
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 linux-headers-6.8.0-41-generic

 nvidia-dkms-545

 linux-headers-generic-hwe-24.04

 nvidia-driver-545

 linux-generic-hwe-24.04

 linux-image-6.8.0-41-generic

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Помогите решить эту проблему

apt-get install -f?
